# Force the System's Default .NET Framework to Prior Version

Tags: .net, default

Is there a way to make my programs open by default with .NET Framework 3.5 instead of 4.0 on Windows 7 (unless the application was specifically targeted at 4.0)?

(Note: I am **not** asking for project targets; I'm asking for a system-wide switch, independent of the application.)

Comment: So you are saying that if an application is specifically targetted to 3.5, it normally opens in 4.0 and you need to "force" it to 3.5? I cannot believe this.

Comment: ... Doesn't it? Maybe I'm mistaken then, thanks for pointing it out; let me double-check the program I ran...

Comment: @Will: No. :D
(Well, okay, I'll tell you, but please don't let the reason digress from answering the question: because .NET 3.5 (or rather 2.0) loads faster than .NET 4.0 on Windows 7. Waaay faster.)

Comment: The "run in latest" was the behaviour from 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0. This changed with 4.0: a 2.0/3.0/3.5 assembly will only load into 4.0 is the correct version of .NET is not available (or rules are overridden in a `.config` of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always thought that when I have got both .NET 3.5 and 4.0 installed, then all applications specifically targetted to 3.5 always choose to run on 3.5 without any additional "forces".

edit: OK, I searched in books and found that this is correct.

Comment: Funny... then why do the .NET 4.0 mscoree.dll and mscoreei.dll get loaded into Reflector when it's run, before I load any assemblies? (I've changed the configuration file to not include .NET 4.0 as a `supportedRuntime`, so it shouldn't be loaded at all, especially when .NET 2.0 has first priority...)

Comment: @Lambert: `mscoree.dll` is the .NET loader: it opens the entry point assembly and then determines the best match available .NET version to load (including any `.config` overrides). `mscoree.dll` is updated with each new CLI version, to add support for that new version. Summary: `mscoree.dll` is *not* .NET (just like kernal32.dll isn't: but is still loaded into every .NET process).

Comment: @Richard +1 for provided details

Comment: @Lambert: [Additional] If you want to look for an assembly that will tell you the running .NET version for a process: look at the version of `mscorlib.dll` (or `mscorlib.ni.dll` when pre-JIT'ed). Also note that with .NET 4, both .NET V2 *and V4 can be loaded into the same Windows process.